# Edit application.yml of jhipster from module

Tags: jhipster

I'm created a module of jhipster for integrate rabbitmq.

When I install the module, the module add for me the dependency in pom by:

```
        this.addMavenDependency("org.springframework.cloud", "spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit");
        this.addMavenDependency("org.springframework.cloud", "spring-cloud-starter-sleuth");
        this.addMavenDependency("org.springframework.boot", "spring-boot-starter-cache");
```

When I regenerare a entity the module create the publisher and channel class.

To here all fine, but i nedd to add chennel confing in application.yml!
Is present a function in BaseGenerator, or other part, like addMavenDependency for add config in application.yml?

Tks in advance

Comment: I never used it but I know each sub generators expose a needle API to enable you to inject custom content into specific files and this is what you used for pom.xml, in your case it should be in https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/tree/main/generators/server/needle-api but I did not find anything for app properties here and no needle comments in the yml.ejs templates either https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/tree/main/generators/server/templates/src/main/resources/config So you probably need to request it on github.

Comment: Given the importance of indentation for yaml, I suppose it would be very hard to have a needle comment in app properties because JHipster could not imagine all places where you would like to inject. Alternatively, you could define a rabbitmq profile and its own application-rabbitmq.yml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have used not standard method, but work, using js-yaml library

```
            const yaml = require('js-yaml');

...

            let configFile = 'src/main/resources/config/application-exchanges.yml';
            let doc = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(configFile, 'utf8'));
            
            if(!doc) {
                doc = {};
            }
            if(!doc.spring) {
                doc.spring = {};
            }
            if(!doc.spring.cloud) {
                doc.spring.cloud = {};
            }
            if(!doc.spring.cloud.stream) {
                doc.spring.cloud.stream = {};
            }
            if(!doc.spring.cloud.stream.bindings) {
                doc.spring.cloud.stream.bindings = {};
            }

            doc.spring.cloud.stream.bindings[`createUpdate${this.entityClass}-Output`] = {
                destination: `createUpdate${this.entityClass}Exchange`,
                contentType: 'application/json'
            }
            doc.spring.cloud.stream.bindings[`delete${this.entityClass}-Output`] = {
                destination: `delete${this.entityClass}Exchange`,
                contentType: 'application/json'
            }

            fs.writeFileSync(configFile, yaml.dump(doc), 'utf8');
```